# DRF serializer related object with unique constraint

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm working on an API using django rest framework.

I have a `Review` object that has a `job_id` FK pointing to a `Job` object, with a unique constraint on that FK (there can only be 1 review per job).

In my `JobSerializer` I can easily include related reviews as a list with something like this:

```
class JobSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    reviews = ReviewSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='review_set')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = [..., 'reviews', ...]
```

This will serialize my job with a `reviews` field containing a list of serialized reviews.

However given the unique constraint on `job_id` I know there's always 0 or 1 reviews and the list is unnecessary. How would I update this to make the API more semantically correct and return instead a `review` field that's not a list but can be null?

I tried setting `many=False` (or removing it) and this breaks with an AttributeError on one of the Review's FKs - but I think that's due to how the `JobSerializer` fetches reviews without `many=True` as I imagine I need to declare the relationship differently in the sample above.

Comment: I think you need to use onetoone field instead of ForeignKey

Answer (score 1):

The best soluition is using `OneToOneField`. But you want to use ForeignKey then you can use `SerializerMethodField()` in your serializer.

```py
class JobSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    reviews = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = [..., 'reviews', ...]
    def get_reviews(self, obj):
         review = obj.review_set.first()
         return ReviewSerializer(review).data
```